# Setting dynamic parameter in Flask's url_for() from JQuery's $.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I have some javascript that queries the server and returns a value that will be used as the parameter for the redirect url:

```
<script>
    $.post("/api/server", post_data, function(result) {
        var parameter = result['parameter'];

        // Do page redirect, but how do I pass my paramter to url_for()???
        window.location = "{{ url_for('doit', param=???) }}";
    });
</script>
```

The flask route:

```
@app.route("/doit/<param>")
def doit(param):
    print param
    return render_template("done.html")
```

Basically, when the `$.post` completes, it returns a value that I need as the parameter for the page redirect. How can I dynamically create this page redirect URL?

Comment: you are missing some concepts about client side vs server side code ... js always runs on client side ... your template is interpreted on the server side ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes you are right. I had a brain fart. The better way is to store it in the user's session and then access that in the new request.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "{{ url_for('doit', param="+parameter+") }}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being dumb. I can store results in my user's session and then access it later in the new request.